# c++ std::thread: Is this code guaranteed to deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading, deadlock

The following code is from [modernescpp](http://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/prefer-locks-to-mutexes). I understand that when the lock_guard in the main thread holding the mutex causes the deadlock. But since the created thread should start to run once it is initialized. Is there a chance that after line 15 the functions lock_guard on line 11 already grabbed coutMutex so the code runs without any problem? If it is possible, under what circumstance the created thread 
will run first?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex coutMutex;

int main(){

  std::thread t([]{
    std::cout << "Still waiting ..." << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(coutMutex); // Line 11
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
  );
  // Line 15
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(coutMutex);
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    t.join();
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like it should be easy for `main` to blast through to the `join` before the thread even gets a chance to start. `main` will have the mutex. Game over.

Comment: It is a race but I expect there is a low chance of it not deadlocking.

Comment: Is it mainly due to the created thread has `std::cout << ...<<std::endl stuff`?

Comment: The deadlock has nothing to do with the cout. It's all about the scope of the lock. At the bottom of that page they show the fix. If main gets the mutex first and holds it for the join you have a deadlock because the thread never can finish. With the updated code the scope of the lock is reduced to only the block containing the cout. When it hits the join the lock is released.

Comment: Circumstances will be mostly dumb luck. Nothing you can count on. If the thread manages to immediately interrupt `main` and get to the mutex first the program won't lock. I give it very low odds.

Comment: It is not _guaranteed_ to deadlock, but I guarantee that deadlock is possible if not probable.

Comment: @drescherjm In both of the solutions, the change of the scopes just make sure the mutex is released before locked. I believe for locking mutex issues, it is all about timing. And that is all about my question, the timing.

Comment: ***And that is all about my question, the timing*** It's very likely that main will get the lock first. It depends on the OS scheduler how long between creating the thread and starting it. Also if you only had 1 core it could be less likely to deadlock perhaps the OS would switch to running the thread putting the thread that runs main in the scheduling queue before it hit the lock.

Comment: The real problem here is that `join()` is called while the `mutex` is locked.  Move the `join()` call out of that block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so the answer will be posted as an answer, not a comment:

- No, this code is not *guaranteed* to deadlock.
- Yes, this code is *quite likely* to deadlock.

In particular, it's possible for the main thread to create the subordinate thread, and then both get suspended. From that point, it's up to the OS scheduler to decide which to run next. Since the main thread was run more recently, there's a decent chance it will select the subordinate thread to run next (assuming it attempts to follow something vaguely like round-robin scheduling in the absence of a difference in priority, or something similar giving it a preference for which thread to schedule).

There are various ways to fix the possibility of deadlock. One obvious possibility would be to move the `join` to just outside the scope in which the main thread holds the mutex:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex coutMutex;

int main(){

  std::thread t([]{
    std::cout << "Still waiting ..." << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(coutMutex); // Line 11
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
    }
  );
  // Line 15
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard(coutMutex);
    std::cout << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;
  }
  t.join();
}
```

I'd also avoid locking a mutex for the duration of using `std::cout`. `cout` is typically slow enough that doing so will make contention over the lock quite likely. It's typically doing to be better to (for only one example) format the data into a buffer, put the buffer into a queue, and have a single thread that reads items from the queue and shoves them out to `cout`. This way you only have to lock for long enough to add/remove a buffer to/from the queue.

Comment: `std::cout` is a global resource cannot protect itself against concurrent access by multiple threads, which can result in inconsistent output (e.g. output from the thread interleaved with output from `main()`).  If you care about output operations being complete, it is necessary to synchronise usage of it (e.g. using a mutex)